# VTK works with real X, crashes with Xvfb

Tags: python, linux, x11, vtk

I'm debugging a 3rd party Python script that implements headless image processing with the VTK library. When run with a regular X window session, it works as expected, flashing a window for a split second. When run against Xvfb (virtual framebuffer in memory), it crashes. The script goes like this (fluff omitted):

```
inname = args[0]
outname = args[1]

from vtk import *

reader = vtkPLYReader()
reader.SetFileName(inname)

gf = vtkGraphicsFactory
gf.SetOffScreenOnlyMode(1)
gf.SetUseMesaClasses(1)
if_ = vtkImagingFactory
if_.SetUseMesaClasses(1)

mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
actor = vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)

renderer = vtkRenderer()
renderWindow = vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindow.SetSize(xsize, ysize)
renderWindow.SetOffScreenRendering(1)
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
renderer.AddActor(actor)
renderer.SetBackground(1, 1, 1)
renderWindow.Render()          #<------------ This line crashes

wif = vtkWindowToImageFilter()
wif.SetInput(renderWindow)
wif.Update()

writer = vtkPNGWriter()
writer.SetFileName(outname)
writer.SetInput(wif.GetOutput())
writer.Write()
```

The crash message goes:

```
ERROR: In /builddir/build/BUILD/VTK/Rendering/vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 404
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x26942e0): Could not find a decent visual

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Xvfb runs as a service; its command line is:

```
 /usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -ac -extension GLX
```

`DISPLAY` is set for `:99` for the testing. The OS is RHEL 6.

Any comments what's a "visual" and how do I enable one in Xvfb are welcome.

EDIT: Running `glxinfo` gives a similar message:

```
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

But the GLX extension is right there in the command line. The Xvfb log doesn't have any error messages.

EDIT2: but when I do `xdpyinfo -queryExtensions`, GLX is not listed.

Comment: try `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=y`?

Comment: `-extension` *disables* the extension. You want `+extension`.

Answer (score 2):

I use Xvfb to run selenium tests, but I use the module [xvfbwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xvfbwrapper), it's a lightweight module for Xvfb

Below the code:

```
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
display = Xvfb()
display.start()
[ yourcode ]
display.stop()
```

Comment: I was trying to compile VTK with VTK_OPENGL_HAS_OSMESA ON, tests were never ok to a 100%. This saved my day. Thanks.